# Inserting variable values into MySQL database; I'm using (%s) but getting syntax error

Tags: python, mysql

table name: 'tickers_list' (table has only 1 column)

column name: 'Ticker'

The following works:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tickers_list (Ticker) VALUES ('AAPL')"
mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
```

But when I try to set it up to accept variables, it's not working:

```
symbol = 'AAPL'
sql = "INSERT INTO tickers_list (Ticker) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.execute(sql, symbol)
mydb.commit()
```

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If your values of tickets are numbers, use %d.

Comment: The tickers are strings, such as AAPL, MSFT, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute with a tuple, and a tuple *must* contain at least one `,`. In Python for a single value this means:

```
mycursor.execute(sql, (symbol,))
```

Which does look a bit weird, but it's just how it is. For multiple values it looks more normal, no trailing `,` is necessary.

Comment: thanks! Haven't run into this before b/c I had only inserted multiple values prior to this, so those were tuples w/o my realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what tadman says, strings need quotes:

```
... ("%s") ...
```